# How to improve accuracy of model in deep learning LSTM algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, lstm, data-science

I'm trying to predict 'news' data by 'LSTM Many to One' model. I used keras. What should I change in my model to increase accuracy?

Current accuracy is  : 55%

number of labels are : 68

data dimensions:

```
  train_seq_x (16254, 499)
  encoded_train_y (16254, 68)
  test_seq_x (1807, 499)
  test_y (1807,)
```

Model definition:

```
def train_model(classifier, feature_vector_train, label, feature_vector_valid, is_neural_net):

     classifier.fit(feature_vector_train, label,epochs=10,batch_size=32,validation_split=0.05,shuffle=False)

     #predict the labels on validation dataset
     predictions = classifier.predict(feature_vector_valid)

     if is_neural_net:
        predictions = predictions.argmax(axis=-1)

     return metrics.accuracy_score(predictions, test_y)

def create_rnn_lstm():
    input_layer = layers.Input((train_seq_x.shape[1], ))

    embedding_layer = layers.Embedding(len(word_index) + 1, 300, weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=False)(input_layer)

    lstm_layer1 = layers.LSTM(128)(embedding_layer)

    output_layer2 = layers.Dense(68, activation="softmax")(lstm_layer1)

    model = models.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer2)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(), loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model

classifier = create_rnn_lstm()
classifier.summary()
accuracy = train_model(classifier, train_seq_x, encoded_train_y, test_seq_x, is_neural_net=True)
print "LSTM, Word Embeddings",  accuracy
```

Comment: why only 10 epochs. Also, is softmax the best activation function for LSTM ?

Comment: I am new to this. Please suggest?

Comment: The most common approach is to increase the number of epochs and use a better activation function.

Comment: To add to @AmreshGiri's advice, it would be best to try a few other activations.  I've found sigmoid or tanh, can perform best with an LSTM (which, by design, is less susceptible to the vanishing gradient problem).  Also worth trying others too, of course.  When tuning hyperparameters manually, I usually start with learning rate, then look at architecture (size, depth), then activation, regularisation, normalisation etc. before finally tweaking the learning rate again.  That said, look into using random search or bayesian methods for tuning.  Be wary of overfitting with those though!